# How to handle an asynchronous response in a java library?

Tags: java, multithreading, asynchronous, response

I am developing a library which sends an asynchronous request to a server (in another thread).

Our clients will use this library, and I am thinking of the best way how to get this handled by them. The response might follow in seconds to a minute. I am doing this using the jersey-client and there already exists a listener which will be called in the other "async" thread.

So I have a shared ressource which will be "filled" with the response by the listener, but the main-thread has to call it to retrieve the response.

Is there a better way how the client might access or be "notified" that the response has arrived? Something like an EventNotifier? (If i implement something like this, shouldn't there exist something like polling on the notifier, but this means that there might exist another thread, which has to do this).

I have no influence on the client who is using my library, I can only make their life easier with an appropriate design of the library-functions they call.

Comment: The simplest thing to do is to make it appear that the request is synchronous even if it is asynchronous down stream. If the client wants it to appear asynchronous, you need to change their interface and I would discuss with them how they want it changed.

Answer (score 2):

What is the servlet container version you are trying to use ? Servlet 3.0 has [builtin support](https://blogs.oracle.com/enterprisetechtips/entry/asynchronous_support_in_servlet_3) for it

Comment: It's a clientside library, using Jersey-Client for accessing a rest-interface.